# Approximating for $a \gg b$

Tags: approximation

I'd like to know how I could go about making approximations where one quantity is much smaller or larger than another.

For example, the expression $\frac{1}{b(a +b)}$ is approximately equal to $\frac{1}{ab}$ when $a \gg b$

But of course, simply taking the infinite limit of a does not yield the right result

i.e.

```
Limit[1/((a + b) b), a -> ∞]
```

gives a result of `0`. It is the ratio of $a$ and $b$ that needs to approach infinity. One cannot do this directly via

```
Limit[1/((a + b) b), a/b -> ∞]
```

and one can get the right answer by substituting an explicit ratio via transformations such as  `/. (a -> r b)`

So how do I get the result I require?

Comment: Why not use `Series[]` on the denominator and then use `Normal[]` for truncation?

Comment: @J.M. A sensible solution for the example I gave, but I was hoping for a more general approach. What if I have `ArcTan[a+b]`

Comment: You might just need more terms to capture the behavior. `In[128]:= e1 = ArcTan[a + b];
f1 = Normal[Series[e1, {a, Infinity, 2}]]
{e1, f1} /. {a -> 100, b -> 1.}

Out[129]= -(1/a) + b/a^2 + \[Pi]/2

Out[130]= {1.56089566021, 1.56089632679}`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Your suggestion is the continuation of what I initially proposed, but what Lucas claimed "fails badly" - so I think he really wanted something that *looks* like what he wrote - numerical accuracy wasn't enough for him. That's why I settled on the `O` method instead.

Comment: @Jens Numerical accuracy would be fine, but as I explained, a series approximation is only numerically accurate for some values, whereas, there are clearly ways of doing it (a you have demonstrated) that do not assume, additionally, that $a$ is absolutely large (as opposed to *comparatively* large with respect to $b$)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about this:

```
Normal@Series[1/((a + b) b), {a, Infinity, 1}]

(* ==> 1/(a b) *)

Normal@Series[ArcTan[a + b], {a, Infinity, 1}]

(* ==> -(1/a) + Pi/2 *)
```

**Edit in response to comment**

Having been told what the desired result for `ArcTan[a+b]` is, it looks like the following expansion method might be what's needed. At least it's consistent with the information provided so far:

```
Normal[1/((a + O[b] + b) b)]

(* ==> 1/(a b) *)

Normal[ArcTan[a + b + O[b]]]

(* ==> ArcTan[a] *)
```

This uses the big-o notation, [`O`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/O.html), directly in the expression.

To automate what I did above, I would use the following `Rule` to implement the statement $b\ll a$ in a given `expression`:

```
expression/.a->(a+O[b])
```

This will cause any powers $b^n$ with $n> 0$ to be dropped when they appear in a sum with $a$.

Comment: The behaviour I would like is that the second on returns ArcTan[a], which would correct for $b \ll a \ll 1$. The series approximation fails quite badly.

Comment: @Lucas Whether to call it failure depends on what precisely you consider the small parameter. The info you initially gave is not sufficient to define what you wanted to do with `ArcTan`, so I picked one of many ways to do it.

Comment: I hope I didn't come across as dismissive, I appreciate the effort. By $a \gg b$ I mean something along the lines of $b = k a$ where $0 < k < $ something small - the series expansion assumes more than this alone.

Comment: @Lucas Maybe the edited answer does what you want...

Comment: Maybe, I'll have to figure out exactly what it's doing. Looks promising.

Comment: To the extent I can't think of a counter example I think it is right, though I really don't know what it's doing.

Comment: @Lucas, Jens is expanding the argument with respect to the smaller parameter `b`; `ArcTan[]` is smart enough to then know what to do if given a series as an argument.