# Simplify expression assuming b>>c using big O notation

Tags: approximation

So I found in [Approximating for $a \gg b$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112483/approximating-for-a-gg-b)

that I can use big O notation to emulate a>>b behavior. However, when I try that with the following equation, I get an undesired result.

Expression:

```
Normal[((c + 2 b) a)/((c + d) (c + b)) /. {b -> b + O[c]}]
```

Expected:

```
2a/(c+d)
```

Actual return:

```
2a/d
```

Where in the above, I'm trying to state that b>>c. Therefore the b in the numerator and the b in the denominator should just cancel.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: This variant seems about right. Rewrite `b` as a function of `c` and some "small" epsilon, then expand in that epsilon. `In[521]:= Normal[
 Series[((c + 2 b) a)/((c + d) (c + b)) /. {b -> c/eps}, {eps, 0, 0}]]

Out[521]= (2 a)/(c + d)`

Comment: Why not `((c + 2 b) a)/((c + d) (c + b)) + O[b, Infinity] // Normal`?

Comment: Those ways do work for this specific equation, but they don't capture the meaning of ```b>>c```. If I use either of those methods on ```((c + 2 b) a)/((c + d) (c + b) (b + e))``` I get ```0```. Though in hindsight, I see that the method I found doesn't really capture the meaning either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just do a series expansion of `b` at infinity. For example:

```
Series[((c+2 b) a)/((c+d) (c+b)), {b, Infinity, 0}] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{2 a}{c+d}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^1\right)$

For your example in the comments:

```
Series[((c+2 b) a)/((c+d) (c+b)(b+e)), {b, Infinity, 1}] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{2 a}{b (c+d)}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^2\right)$

If only `c` is much smaller than `b`, you can use Daniel's answer in the comments:

```
Normal[Series[((c+2 b) a)/((c+d) (c+b)(b+\[Epsilon])) /. b -> c/\[Epsilon], {\[Epsilon], 0, 2}]] /. \[Epsilon]->c/b
```

> (2 a)/(b (c + d)) - (a c)/(b^2 (c + d))

Compare this to the above approach where everything is smaller than `b`:

```
Normal @ Series[((c+2 b) a)/((c+d) (c+b)(b+e)), {b, Infinity, 2}]
```

> (2 a)/(b (c + d)) + (-a c - 2 a e)/(b^2 (c + d))

Answer (score 1):

Big $O$ notation is used to write a term to first order in a selected term. Here starting with the term

$$\frac{a\left(2b+c\right)}{\left(b+c\right)\left(c+d\right)}$$

and assuming that $b\gg c$, the goal is to write the fraction in first order in $\frac{b}{c}$. By multiplying the numerator and denominator by $1/b^2$ and making the substitutions $\tilde{a}\equiv a/b$, $\tilde{c}\equiv c/b$, and $\tilde{d}\equiv a/d$  we can rewrite the original term as

$$\frac{\tilde{a}\left(2+\tilde{c}\right)}{\left(1+\tilde{c}\right)\left(\tilde{c}+\tilde{d}\right)}$$

Now assuming that $b\gg c$ results in $\tilde{c}\approx 0$, thus we can do a Taylor expansion about the point $c=0$ using [Series](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html).

```
Series[(a (2 + c))/((1 + c) (c + d)), {c, 0, 0}]
```

this will give the output

```
2a/d + O[c]^1
```

Simplifying the original equation when $b\gg c$ is not as simple as just crossing out the $c$ terms in the numerator and the denominator due to the presence of the additional $c$ dependent cross terms resulting from the multiplication in the denominator.

Comment: Hi cphys, thank you for the explanation. I see now why my method was erroneous. Do you know of a method to accomplish ```b>>c```?